# Compare String to today's date

Tags: javascript

I have a date in the format as "16-Jun-2015" and I need to compare it to today's date to see it is not larger.

Since my input date is a string I first converted to a date object:

```
new Date("16-Jun-2015");
```

Then I took this to compare to today's date:

```
if(date.compare(new Date("16-Jun-2015"), new Date()) > 0){
   //Do stuff if input is larger than today's date
}
```

The *new Date("16-Jun-2015")* returns the value '*Invalid date*.' How can I compare these dates? I also cannot use any third-party Date libraries, as I do not own the entire codebase I'm working with.

The duplicate question message is incorrect as that question only displays parsing, but not comparing.

Comment: [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: What is `date.compare` What function is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Date.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Comment: date.compare I got from looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15063825/5003986

Comment: That date works for me in Chrome, but it's not really in the correct RFC2822/ISO8601 format, so you might have to split it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the format you are providing is not standardized, it's not guaranteed to be supported by the `Date` constructor.

There are multiple approaches to solving this problem, but the easiest one is to use a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which has its own parsing functions that you can control with format specifiers.

For example:

```
if (moment("16-Jun-2015","D-MMM-YYYY").isAfter())
    ...
```

Note that in this example, the `isAfter` function uses the current date and time because it was not passed any parameters.

However, since you said you couldn't use a library, consider a simple parsing function of your own, such as:

```
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

function parseDate(s){
    var parts = s.split("-");
    var d = parts[0];
    var m = months.indexOf(parts[1]);
    var y = parts[2];
    return new Date(y, m, d);
}
```

Which you can simply call like so:

```
if (parseDate("16-Jun-2015") > new Date())
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! I unfortunately cannot insert additional javascript libraries into my application as I do not own it.

Comment: @user2924127 - I updated my answer with a second approach that does not require a library.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) surrounding the `Date` object in JavaScript.

In essence, your usage of the `new Date('16-Jun-2015')` is invalid as the Date constructor expects a very specific input format.

This means you'll need to convert your date format ("16-Jun-2015") into a compatible format, either [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601) or [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14).

Converting your date's format to one of these standards is unavoidable. This process can be made easier with third-party libraries, like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: How do I compare then to today's date?

Comment: You'll need to convert your date format into a standard format accepted by JavaScript's `Date` object.

Comment: `Date.parse()` still requires a compatible date string, either in ISO-8601 or RFC2822.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I unfortunately cannot insert additional javascript libraries into my application as I do not own it.