# Remove table row if mapped td equals something

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Hi I have an events list that I want to show only upcoming events.
I want to remove past events table rows if date is less than todays date.

But I cannot get the associated row to remove?

Thanks

```
var date = jQuery('tr.Entries').find('td.event-date > a').text();
var dates = jQuery('tr.Entries').find('td.event-date > a').map(function() {
  return jQuery(this).text();
}).get();

var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate = ("0" + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();

jQuery.each(dates, function(index, value) {
  if (value < currentDate) {
    console.log("true");
    if (date === value) {
      console.log("true");
      jQuery(date).parent().remove(); //how to map table date to the row and delete the row?
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(date)`, but `date` is simple string from `.text()` does it contains any selector?

Comment: why not do this server side, ie don't output the html in the first place if it is older, would be much more efficient

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove past events if date is less than todays date.

Do it in the initial filter itself

```
var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate = ( "0" + currentDate.getDate() ).slice(-2) + "/" + ( "0" + ( currentDate.getMonth() + 1 ) ).slice(-2) + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear();

jQuery( 'tr.Entries' ).find( 'td.event-date > a' ).each( function() {
  var date = jQuery( this ).text();
  if ( date < currentDate )
  {
    jQuery( this ).closest( ".event-date " ).remove(); //remove the parent which has lesser date `a`
  }
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for the input. I think I have confused myself - I may need to convert the `date` in to readable format to compare? it is removing what seems to be random dates

Comment: Will it be possible for you to add relevant markup to your question in a more verifiable manner?